# How can I get single page inner text?

Tags: javascript, uiwebview

Using CSS3 columns to take a somewhat large text document and make it scroll horizontally.
Here is demo of code.- http://jsfiddle.net/wojtiku/bFKpa/

I use "document.documentElement.innerText" js code ,get all document text,but I want to get a column text,How to do ?

Comment: I don't think you can do that...

Comment: Yes, what you're performing is a visual transformation using CSS3 - the DOM doesn't reflect that change, and so there's no logical way to access those columns.

Comment: For all the answers using `innerText` (introduced in HTML5), please note that there are browsers that don't support it. Include a fork [textContent](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#Node3-textContent) (introduced in DOM 3 Core) also.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the root element of each column and the `innerText` from that element.

```
var elements = document.getElementById("container").getElementsByTagName("p");
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
    console.log("COLUMN " + i + "\n");
    console.log(elements[i].innerText);
};
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4mHCb/3/

You can open your browser's JS console and see the output (ctrl+shift+j in chrome).

**EDIT**

Thanks to voithos for pointing out what I overlooked.  Taking what he said into account, I'm pretty sure there is no way to do this accurately.  However, here is a total hack which approximates what you are looking for.  It uses an offscreen [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial) and the 2d context's [mesaureText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Drawing_text_using_a_canvas#measureText%28%29) method:
http://jsfiddle.net/4mHCb/5/

```
var elements = document.getElementById("container").getElementsByTagName("p");
var g2d = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d");
var containerStyle = document.getElementById("container").style;

var columnWidth = 150;
var lineHeight = 18;
var columnHeight = 300;
var linesPerCol = columnHeight / lineHeight;
var results = [];
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
    var colText = elements[i].innerText;
    var textWidth = g2d.measureText(colText).width;
    var numCols = textWidth / (columnWidth * linesPerCol);

    var charIdx = 0;
    for (var column = 0; column < numCols; ++column) {
       var currString = "";
       var currTextWidth = 0;
       for (; charIdx < colText.length && currTextWidth < columnWidth*linesPerCol;    ++charIdx) {
           currString += colText[charIdx];
           currTextWidth = g2d.measureText(currString).width;
       }
       results.push(currString);
   }
}

for(var column = 0; column < results.length; ++column) {
   console.log("COLUMN: " + column);
   console.log(results[column]);
}
```

​

Comment: But notice that the paragraphs span across multiple columns. This doesn't answer his question.

Comment: @voithos updated the answer with an interesting hack that'll return an approximation of the text in each column...

Comment: Bravo, sir! As you probably guessed, this method is not quite so accurate - but I wasn't aware of that method of the 2D context. Perhaps the accuracy can be improved by iterating through the possible breakpoints for each paragraph, making sure that the breakpoint lies on a space between words, getting the textwidth of those substrings, and making sure that they don't exceed the column width. Then, continue doing so, amassing the lines of a column, all the while keeping track of the accumulated column height, until you get to the end... But regardless, well done, good effort.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, this is what you are trying to get..

```
 var childElement= document.getElementById("container").getElementsByTagName("p");
 for(var i=0;i<childElement.length;i++)
 {
   alert(childElement[i].innerHTML);  
 }
```

The above snippets return collection of para tag which you can loop through and get the html content.

​

Comment: Almost a -1. Replace `innerHTML` with either `textContent` or `innerText` based on a feature test to see which is supported (some browsers support one, others both).

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way to do so. The columns don't exist as separate DOM elements, no more than lines of text do.

You might be able to look for the column breaks (e.g, by inserting a bunch of zero-size inline elements into the text and looking at their locations), but it'd be a messy and error-prone process.